# Is there any way to chop vegetables quickly without using a knife?

Tags: equipment, cutting

I sometimes need to have chopped, or more specifically, *shredded* vegetables for coleslaw or other similar dishes.

Usually I use a knife, but it can be time consuming.

I have tried using using food processors like the Ninja, but it completely fails even when you put the machine on "chop" setting. The problem is that it cuts the cabbage into tiny little pieces. Also, the pieces are square, not long strips the way you need to shred for coleslaw.

Is there any automated way (available to an individual cook) to do this?

I know there are machines that do this because I see coleslaw mix in the supermarket, but those might be big machines that are not available for kitchens.

Comment: @rumtscho : The highest ranked answer for that first one you claim answers the question is “a sharp knife and practice”, when this question is specifically *without* using a knife

Comment: For the cabbage, see https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/100449/67 .  For carrots and similarly hard veggies, a shredding disk on a food processor, a box grater, or a mandoline with a julienne blade.

Comment: @Joe 1) if the knife is really faster than all other methods, then it is also a very important information for the OP here (who only asked for something else because they assumed other methods are faster) 2) the top answer mentions the mandoline too, and OP already tried a food processor and 3) even if theoretically, the top answer of another question would have been wrong, this is not a problem that is solved by leaving a dupe open. Two wrongs don't make a right.

Comment: This question asks if there is an automated method that does long strips, like maybe a salad shooter, a Kitchen Aid attachment, or something.